# Azure Database for MySQL - mysqlimport command

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database, csv

So I'm trying to accomplish the goal of performing a mysqlimport on a Azure MySQL 8 database and I get the following error:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1227 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

I have created a sample schema: `CREATE SCHEMA test;`

I have created a sample table: `CREATE TABLE test.test_import (Data VARCHAR(50));`

I have a test csv (test_import.csv) with one column of text. Note that the name of the csv matches the test import table as well as the one field inside of the csv, so no issues with that part.

I have attempted to grant myself SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN like the error suggests doing, but have been unable to do so with these Azure databases:

```
GRANT SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO tester@'%';

Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the GRANT OPTION privilege(s) for this operation
```

Lastly, here is the mysqlimport command (don't worry about the credentials, they're not real).

```
.\mysqlimport.exe --host="testmysql8.mysql.database.azure.com" --user="tester@testmysql8" --password="test123!" test test_import.csv
```

Comment: you have no rights to that  so try to load https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: What's odd is that this is a new issue for us. Previous azure databases allowed us (and those that haven't been downloaded still do) to use mysqlimport. So changing to the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command would require me to change a large number of scripts, which I would prefer not to do. I have written a .NET console application to wrap the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command which does work for the time being on our test server, but I'd like to see if I can resolve it using the method that has worked for us for a long time now.

Comment: i fear tha can only the support say, but i think it is written in the contract